# Simple Buttons with GPIO, not working

Tags: gpio, python

I' following [this tutorial](http://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/) to have two buttons working with my Pi.

The code I have is the same:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    if(GPIO.input(23) ==1):
       print(“Button 1 pressed”)
    if(GPIO.input(24) == 0):
       print(“Button 2 pressed”)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

While I don't have any response from the #23, the Pi reboots itself when I press #24.

I'm using an [Adafruit Assembled Pi T-Cobbler Breakout + Cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1754).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, that the wiring at your breakout box is correct?

Comment: Make sure your cobbler is inserted the right way around.   If it's back to front you can cause damage,  If the multiway cable has one coloured one check it goes pin1 to pin1.

Comment: Thanks @joan. Actually you were right: the cobbler was the other way round. This still puzzles me, as I followed the picture on the ADAfruit page. Therefore I think there is some sort of production mistake...

Comment: The cobbler and cable should be keyed so that they only fit one way.  If they are not keyed then I'd count that as a design error.  Unfortunately the expansion header isn't keyed so there will be a right and a wrong way of inserting the cable over the pins.