# i2c not detecting any connections

Tags: gpio, i2c

Im using the ADS1115 with my raspi. I have the GPIO connected with a T-cobbler.
When I run `i2cdetect -y 1` it shows that nothing is connected. 
I've checked my connections in terms of soldering and wiring and they all seem fine.
Im trying to run the simple test in the Adafruit library but getting an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "simpletest.py", line 42, in <module>
values[i] = adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN)
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 192, in read_adc
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_ADS1x15/ADS1x15.py", line 128, in _read
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 127, in writeList
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 274, in write_i2c_block_data
IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Any suggestions?
[image][Wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPJpy.jpg)

Comment: Try without the cobbler.  The ribbon cable can be the wrong way around in the cobbler or in the Pi.

Comment: I've test the 3v3 and 5v outputs from the bread board so I don't think that's the problem. How could I use it without the cobbler if there still is a problem?

Comment: It's worth sanity checking that you're reading 5V from the 5V pin and 3.3V from the 3.3V pin. On [at least](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/gpio-stuck-in-high-mode/41587) [a couple](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/simple-buttons-with-gpio-not-working) of occasions very similar things have come up here. Without the cobbler you'll need some [female jumper wires](https://www.adafruit.com/products/266) to go from the Pi's GPIO pins to the pins of your ADC.

Comment: A picture of your wiring to the ADS1115 would be useful.  Also, do you have other I2C devices?  If you plug one of those in, does it show up in the i2cdetect listing?

Comment: The 5V and 3v3 are outputting correctly from the board. I've added images  above if its any help. (By the way I'm aware its not plugged in in the picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. The ADC I was using was faulty. I setup a second one and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. But it was a broken cabel.
The list form sudo i2cdetect -y 1n get 0x48 back, but the GND Cabel was broken. After changing it, it works.
It took me 3 hours to fix it. :-(
Because sudo i2cdetect -y 1 get the right answer.
Now I am happy.